# Ruby on Rails configuration gem difficulty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Ruby on Rails newbie configuration issue:

I screwed up my rails configuration by running "gem install pg".   Now when I try to do a bundle install I get this error:

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:287:in `resolve': Could not find gem 'pg (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine. (Bundler::GemNotFound)

And if I try to reinstall pg gem, I get this:

[image]

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: I think you have to remove this gem `pg` from your Gemfile.

Comment: It looks like if I want to run pg as my local db, I have some configuration issues to work out, because it works OK if I use sqlite as the local db and pg on heroku, but I'd prefer not to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have Postgres installed and working correctly? The [heroku supplied app](http://postgresapp.com/) is the most painless way to it if you havent.

Comment: I have postgres installed locally, but I'm not sure if it is configured correctly for rails.  I have used it recently for django development, but suspect that I have a configuration issue.

Comment: I'd reinstall postgres and try again. I've found the heroku app that I linked to above much easier than homebrew or other installation methods